# Show ToolTip on RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, tooltip

I have a RichTextBox on a WPF Window. Now, I want to show a ToolTip when the user move the mouse over the RichTextBox. The Content of the RichTextBox should depend on the Text which is under the mouse pointer. For this I should get the position of the char, on which the mouse shows to.

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example the tooltip will show the next character where the caret is.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <RichTextBox ToolTipOpening="rtb_ToolTipOpening" ToolTip="" />
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
void rtb_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
  RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;

  if (rtb == null)
    return;

  TextPointer position = rtb.GetPositionFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(rtb), false);
  if (position == null)
    return;

  int offset = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(position);

  position = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
  if (position == null)
    return;

  string text = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);

  rtb.ToolTip = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? text.Substring(0, 1) : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben. I need the character at the position where the mouse-cursor is.

Comment: @t.kehl Sorry, somehow i missed that part. Anyway using the [TextPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.aspx)'s [GetCharacterRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getcharacterrect.aspx) method you can write a function that takes a mouse position and finds the character that [contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557979.aspx) that position. Im at work right now, but if you will don't find a solution i will try do it later when im at home.

Comment: Hi Ben. I have no do it on the fallow way: `void rtb_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e) {
            RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
            if (rtb == null) return;

            var position = rtb.GetPositionFromPoint(Mouse.GetPosition(rtb), false);

            if (position == null) return;

            var x = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(position);
            // I can now get the text/character at position x
        }` mmhh - I don't now, how can I add this code so it is mor readable :-( ... do you think, this could work?

Comment: @t.kehl Edited my answer, now its shows the character at the mouse position.