# Set tooltip on range of text in wpf richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox, wpf-4.0

I am trying to set a tooltip on an arbitrary range of text on a richtextbox. Is this possible? If so how would I do it e.g by passing in parameters "from" and "to" as (int) indexes.

Thanks

Comment: A solution based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928809/show-tooltip-on-richtextbox where you handle the event in code behind might be a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following as a starting point:

1. Add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`.
2. Add the following classes to your project:

   ```
   public class TextRangeToolTip
   {
       public int StartPosition { get; set; }

       public int Length { get; set; }

       public object ToolTip { get; set; }

       internal bool IsInRange(int position)
       {
           return this.StartPosition <= position && position < this.StartPosition + this.Length;
       }
   }

   public class TextRangeToolTipCollection : ObservableCollection<TextRangeToolTip> {}

   [ContentProperty("Ranges")]
   public class ToolTipBehavior : Behavior<RichTextBox>
   {
       private const int ToolTipHideMouseDelta = 9;

       public static readonly DependencyProperty RangesProperty
           = DependencyProperty.Register("Ranges", typeof(TextRangeToolTipCollection),
                                         typeof (ToolTipBehavior),
                                         new PropertyMetadata(OnRangesChanged));

       private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;

       private readonly ToolTip toolTip;
       private Point lastMousePosition;

       public TextRangeToolTipCollection Ranges
       {
           get
           {
               return (TextRangeToolTipCollection)this.GetValue(RangesProperty)
                      ?? (this.Ranges = new TextRangeToolTipCollection());
           }
           set { this.SetValue(RangesProperty, value); }
       }

       public ToolTipBehavior()
       {
           this.Ranges = new TextRangeToolTipCollection();

           this.timer = new DispatcherTimer();
           this.timer.Tick += this.TimerOnTick;
           this.timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

           this.toolTip = new ToolTip {Placement = PlacementMode.Relative};
       }

       protected override void OnAttached()
       {
           this.AssociatedObject.ToolTip = this.toolTip;
           this.toolTip.PlacementTarget = this.AssociatedObject;
           ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(this.AssociatedObject, false);

           this.AssociatedObject.MouseMove += this.AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
       }

       protected override void OnDetaching()
       {
           this.timer.Stop();

           this.toolTip.PlacementTarget = null;
           this.AssociatedObject.ToolTip = null;
           this.AssociatedObject.ClearValue(ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty);

           this.AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= this.AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove;
       }

       private void AssociatedObjectOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
       {
           Point currentMousePosition = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(this.AssociatedObject);

           if (this.AssociatedObject.IsMouseCaptured)
           {
               Vector delta = currentMousePosition
                              - this.lastMousePosition;

               if (delta.X*delta.X + delta.Y*delta.Y <= ToolTipHideMouseDelta)
               {
                   this.toolTip.HorizontalOffset = currentMousePosition.X + 10;
                   this.toolTip.VerticalOffset = currentMousePosition.Y + 10;
                   return;
               }

               this.AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
               this.toolTip.IsOpen = false;
           }

           if (this.AssociatedObject.IsMouseOver)
           {
               this.lastMousePosition = currentMousePosition;
               this.timer.Stop();
               this.timer.Start();
           }
       }

       private static void OnRangesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           ((ToolTipBehavior) d).OnRangesChanged((IEnumerable<TextRangeToolTip>) e.OldValue,
                                                 (IEnumerable<TextRangeToolTip>) e.NewValue);
       }

       private void OnRangesChanged(IEnumerable<TextRangeToolTip> oldRanges, IEnumerable<TextRangeToolTip> newRanges)
       {
           var oldObservable = oldRanges as INotifyCollectionChanged;
           if (oldObservable != null)
           {
               CollectionChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(oldObservable, this.OnRangesCollectionChanged);
           }

           var newObservable = newRanges as INotifyCollectionChanged;
           if (newObservable != null)
           {
               CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(newObservable, this.OnRangesCollectionChanged);
           }

           this.UpdateToolTip();
       }

       private void OnRangesCollectionChanged(
           object sender,
           NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
       {
           this.UpdateToolTip();
       }

       private bool SetToolTipData()
       {
           if (this.Ranges == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           TextPointer pointer = this.AssociatedObject.GetPositionFromPoint(this.lastMousePosition, false);
           if (pointer == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           int position = this.AssociatedObject.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(pointer);

           TextRangeToolTip matchingRange = this.Ranges.FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsInRange(position));
           if (matchingRange == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           this.toolTip.Content = matchingRange.ToolTip;
           return true;
       }

       private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
       {
           this.timer.Stop();

           if (this.AssociatedObject.IsMouseOver && this.SetToolTipData())
           {
               this.toolTip.IsOpen = true;
               this.AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
           }
       }

       private void UpdateToolTip()
       {
           if (this.AssociatedObject != null && this.AssociatedObject.IsMouseCaptured && !this.SetToolTipData())
           {
               this.toolTip.IsOpen = false;
               this.AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use it on your `RichTextBox` like this:

   ```
   <RichTextBox>
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <myapp:ToolTipBehavior>
               <myapp:TextRangeToolTip StartPosition="10" Length="4" ToolTip="some" />
               <myapp:TextRangeToolTip StartPosition="15" Length="4" ToolTip="text" />
           </myapp:ToolTipBehavior>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <FlowDocument>
           <Paragraph>This is some text. This is some other text.</Paragraph>
       </FlowDocument>
   </RichTextBox>
   ```

   Alternatively, you can bind a `TextRangeToolTipCollection` to the `Ranges` property like this:

   ```
   <RichTextBox Document="{Binding Document}">
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <myapp:ToolTipBehavior Ranges="{Binding RangeToolTips}" />
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </RichTextBox>
   ```

Getting the positions right is a bit tricky, because WPF counts symbols, not characters. You could extend the `TextRangeToolTip` class to have properties of type `TextPointer` or `TextRange` and construct it using your `FlowDocument` instance.